# Получить последний uri после Get запроса

Tags: c#, парсер, http, uri

Я при помощи парсинга хочу получить все товары из интернет-магазина Розетка по определённой строке. Допустим, я хочу получить гречку, тогда я через HttpClient делаю запрос

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?text=гречка");
```

Но если делать это через браузер, то нас перенаправляет на этот uri: https://rozetka.com.ua/krupy/c4628397/vid-225787=grechka/#search_text=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0

Именно этот uri, на который розетка перенаправляет мне и нужно получить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не очень хороший пример взяли, ибо там не простой редирект.

Если отвечать на ваш вопрос, то последний адрес всегда находится в:

```
response.RequestMessage.RequestUri //https://rozetka.com.ua/ua/search/?text=гречка
```

---

#### Почему это не то, что ожидалось и как получить нужное?

Для этого, давайте проследим за тем, как общается браузер с сервером и какие запросы отправляются:

[image: Анализ сайта]

Как видите, при заходе на сайт, он сразу перенаправляет нас на `https://rozetka.com.ua/ua/search/?text=гречка` и это для сайта конечный результат, больше он не перенаправляет. Ок, но от куда ссылка? Смотрим запросы дальше:

[image: Анализ сайта]

Тут мы сразу видим, что сайт использует API и подгружает все в некий фрейм, а ссылку он берет из `https://search.rozetka.com.ua/ua/search/api/v4/?front-type=xl&text=гречка&lang=ua`

```
{
  "data": {
    "quantities": null,
    "pagination": null,
    "options": [],
    "filters": [],
    "conditions": null,
    "chosen": [],
    "related_options": null,
    "meta": {
      "result_info": null,
      "h1": "",
      "title": "",
      "keywords": "",
      "description": "",
      "navigateTo": {
        "fragment": {
          "search_text": "гречка"
        },
        "fragment_raw": "search_text=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0",
        "host": "rozetka.com.ua",
        "path": "/ua/krupy/c4628397/vid-225787=grechka/",
        "query": [],
        "query_raw": null,
        "scheme": "https",
        "url": "https://rozetka.com.ua/ua/krupy/c4628397/vid-225787=grechka/#search_text=гречка",
        "url_api": ""
      }
    },
    "categories": null,
    "goods": null
  }
}
```

Ну и при помощи JS уже идет подмена адреса в адресной строке, но не редиректом.

Так что, если хотите именно нужную ссылку, то отправляйте запрос на API адрес, а уже от туда вытаскивайте ссылку (десериализация JSON).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Можете пожалуйста подсказать, что за софт вы использовали? Через network в гугле менее удобно работать.

Comment: @NaClnik В ответе использовался `Fiddler Everywhere`, но советую использовать классическую версию (`Fiddler Classic`).